# wordpress ubermenu warnings on nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, amazon-s3

I have a site on my aws server with PHP 7.1 and nginx as server for php. Wordpress latest version is running. Many time about after every 20 minutes I saw 502 error while accessing the site. 
Nginx server logs shows the following warnings.

```
*674241 FastCGI sent in stderr: "m_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 673
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 673
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'submenu_type_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 371
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 673
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_display_calc' in wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/includes/menuitems/UberMenuItem.class.php on line 563
```

After simple googling I got this file: http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/faqs/php-7-1-warnings after which error still the same.

Please provide some useful solution, thanks

Comment: Are you sure the error is the same one after changing the file?
I had this error, but after changing the file I got a different error on line 83, which I was able to solve later.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out that initialisation lines of code

```
// $this->settings['item_display_calc'] = '';
```